# Mysql SET reference Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, set

So I know that within Mysql there is a SET datatype that can be used to hold zero or more than one String element within a single column.

The thing that I would like to do is have a table called EMPLOYEES which has a column called Languages and this column will contain the set of all languages that the employees knows. But there will also be a languages table which contains all the possible languages within the system I need the EMPLOYEES languages set column to reference the IDs of the languages in the languages table.

Is this even possible or is there a better way of tackling this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `set` for this.  This data type is limited to 64 elements (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)).  There are more than 64 languages in the world.

Instead, create a bona fide junction table, with a column for `EmployeeId` and `LanguageId` (and appropriate foreign references to the `Employees` and `Languages` tables)  This also gives you the ability to:

- Include knowledge of the language ("reading", "conversational", "fluent", "native")
- Include date when employee became knowledgeable at that level
- Other information that might be relevant

Also, the `set` data type is specific to MySQL, so if you ever decide to change the underlying database, you would have to create such a junction table (or something similar) anyway.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand what you're saying; for example create a table called EMPLOYEE_LANGUAGES and have the EMPLOYEE ID and the Language ID act as the composite primary key and have that as a way of linking the employee to the language that they know.

Comment: @Hussain1993 . . . Exactly.  That is technically called a "junction" or "association" table.  It is a table that implements a many-to-many relationship.